# How to get the current cursor state (WaitCursor, Arrow, Default, etc) on Windows using Python?

Tags: python, windows

I would like to get the current cursor state using Python (on Windows). In C# you could use the `Cursor.Current` property, but how do you do that in Python?

Thanks!

Comment: What Windows API Python bindings are you using?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Querying the current cursor shape is largely useless. It is controlled by the window under the cursor. That window is at liberty to set the cursor shape to any shape it sees fit.

Comment: I'm trying to automate a process, and I need to wait for an action to finish. The only indicator exists is the cursor, changing from WAITING state to a normal state. How would you solve it?

Comment: Btw, if a window can set it's own shape for the cursor, how does `Cursor.Current` work in C#? Thanks!